# How to represent a quoter and a quotee for a webapp

Tags: layout, lists, gui-design

For my own personal project while I learn PHP, I am creating a web app where friends can quote each other. So a user will come and post what their friend said and their friends can like it and comment on it.

One problem I am having UI wise is how to display both the person being quoted and the person who posted the quote. I think its important to show both because the person posting the quote should be known. I have my own ideas but nothing I'm too excited about.

Drawings and pictures would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's a case of using hierachy to distinguish the users

Have the 'quoter' be the first person, have their name and image listed at the top.
Below that, in a block quote or similar pattern, have the 'quotee' , their quote, and their image?

[image] carlosz

> "I have the simplest tastes. I am always satisfied with the best."
>
> — *Oscar Wilde* [image]

If you wanted to further accentuated that, maybe have the block quote in a defined box, and the 'quotee' to the right hand side

[image] carlosz

```
                "I have the simplest tastes.
                I am always satisfied with the best."
                                                          Oscar Wilde[image]
```

Something like that has an obvious flow. Here's the 'quoter', he's the quote, and here's the 'quotee'.

Comment: I like the second option the best! All the quoters on the left and the quotees on the right. Love it! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an ear icon for the 'overhearer' and a mouth icon for the quoted person. It's a pretty universal way of representing the role of each person and you could use both icons at quite a small size and still convey the meaning clearly.

Comment: I want to use their profile images.

Comment: Sure. They're not mutually exclusive so you could go with both. Just a random suggestion anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Quotes usually have the quotee at the end:

> "I have the simplest tastes. I am always satisfied with the best."
>   — Oscar Wilde

Comment: Agreed. But should I have their picture image next to their name, coming form a speech bubble, and what about the poster?

Comment: Maybe a link to the user profile or expand information on mouse over like the twitter [hovercard](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin#hovercards)