# How to quote images / source code / snippets

Tags: usability, chat

I am building a chat, but this question is not limited to this. In fact, any forum has to have encountered this problem as well.

I wonder **how to quote big content** appropriately, considering the flow of a chat and the amount of space that images or code snippets can take.

I came up with two possible results, but I'm looking forward better ways to do this:

**(1) Copy-pasting the content**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fijPWC.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**(2) Reply just below the content**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foSbjk.png)</sup>

What are your thoughts about this? Do you know any better way?

Comment: They don't appear to be "chats" as such but comments on an image, is that right?

Comment: @DarrylGodden that's right. Although I wanted them to be seen as replies to the image rather than simple like / dislike comments. That's why I'm scared that a fast-paced chat can make these sort of content usabilities' poor.

Comment: Please check this http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7043/how-to-represent-a-quoter-and-a-quotee-for-a-webapp

Answer (score 1):

The similar kind of approach is used in Whatsapp application http://indianexpress.com/article/technology/social/whatsapp-new-quote-message-reply-feature-for-android-beta-2845783/ It's very effective and keeps the reply's in a flow that the users will not miss any replies from other users even in a group where the latest message with reply comes first.

[image]

[image]